# Avoid suggesting same tag twice

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-autocomplete

When you enter a tag, it makes suggestions which you can select from.  If I enter:

SQL-Server

Then I enter

SQL-Se

It suggests SQL-Server even though I've already used this tag.  It would be a little faster to enter tags if it ommited tags that you have already typed as the 2nd suggestion is often the one I want, not the same one again!

Comment: I like this will look at implementing

Comment: Wizard sick cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would certainly help, especially with tags that have version specific tags also. Maybe it would even be easier if one could add several tags at once, selecting multiple ones from the list presented by the suggestions.

[image: multiple selections]

Comment: +1 for the [Font of the Gods](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/comic-sans-the-font-of-the-gods.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about entering tags in the Ask Question page, I don't think it's necessary as only a maximum of five tags are allowed. I guess our eyes are good enough to scan the five tags in one line :)

If you are talking about entering tags in the User Prefs page, then I agree your suggestion would be useful. Or, perhaps even better, show something like this (note the "Added" visual cue):

[image: Tag entering]

(Special credit to @[Ralph Rickenbach](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3724/ralph-rickenbach) :)